# How to use QThread for data transfer between child threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, qthread, pyside2

I want to use QThread in Pyside2 to transfer data between child threads. I want to write an APP read serial data in readThread (child thread), write the data read in writeThread (child thread), and plot the serial data in plot function (main thread). I wrote a demo for this, and the code is as follows:

```
import threading
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLCDNumber, QMessageBox
from PySide2.QtCore import *
import sys
import os

# add environment path of pyside2
envpath = r'E:\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\PySide2\plugins\platforms'
os.environ["QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH"] = envpath

sec = 0    # counter 

# child thread, representing the process of read serial data
class ReadThread(QThread):
        timer = Signal()  # create a signal
        end = Signal()  # create a signal
    
        def run(self):
            print("ReadThread1", threading.current_thread())  # print thread ID
            while True:
                self.sleep(1)  # sleep 1s
                print("ReadThread2", threading.current_thread())  
                if sec == 2:
                    self.end.emit()  # emit end signal
                    break
                self.timer.emit()
    
# chiald thead2, represents write data to txt file
class WriteThread(QThread):
    
        def run(self):
            print("WriteThread", threading.current_thread())  # print thread ID
    
class Counter(QWidget):
    
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(Counter, self).__init__(parent)
    
            self.setWindowTitle("qthreading test")
            self.resize(300, 120)
    
            # add a layout
            layout = QVBoxLayout()
            self.lcdNumber = QLCDNumber()
            layout.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)
            # add a pushbutton 
            button = QPushButton('start')
            layout.addWidget(button)
    
            self.readThread = ReadThread()  # workthread
            self.writeThread = WriteThread()  # writeThread
            self.readThread.timer.connect(self.plot)   
    
            self.readThread.timer.connect(self.writeThread.run) #I want to connect readThread and writeThread
    
            self.readThread.end.connect(self.end)
    
            button.clicked.connect(self.work)
    
            self.setLayout(layout)
    
        # The callback function of readThread (Main Thread), representing the process of plot serial data
        def plot(self):
            global sec
            sec += 1
            self.lcdNumber.display(sec)
            print("countTime", threading.current_thread())  
    
        def end(self):
            QMessageBox.information(self, "message", "stop")
    
        # start readTread and WriteThread when button is clicked
        def work(self):
            self.readThread.start()
            self.writeThread.start()  
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Counter()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I ran the program, the output was as follows:

```
**ReadThread1 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7556)>
WriteThread <_DummyThread(Dummy-2, started daemon 2552)>
ReadThread2 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7556)>
WriteThread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 7536)>
ReadThread2 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7556)>
WriteThread <_MainThread(MainThread, started 7536)>
ReadThread2 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 7556)>**
```

As you can see, at first both readThread and writeThread are in child thread, but as the signal() is emitted, the writeThread becomes running in the main thread while the readThread is in child thread. I don't know what's wrong with my codes. Why isn't the operation done in the child thread when writeThread responds to signal()? It would be nice if you could modify it directly in my code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic error in your logic: You should not directly invoke the run method of a QThread since it is indirectly invoked by the start method, so you notice that at the beginning the "run" method is executed in the secondary thread, and then as You invoke it directly then it will be executed in the thread to which the QObject (WriteThread) belongs, which is the main thread.

If you want to execute a task in a secondary thread depending on a signal then you must create a QObject and move it to a new thread:

```py
class ReadThread(QThread):
    timer = Signal()  # create a signal
    end = Signal()  # create a signal

    def run(self):
        print("ReadThread1", threading.current_thread())  # print thread ID
        while True:
            self.sleep(1)  # sleep 1s
            print("ReadThread2", threading.current_thread())
            if sec == 2:
                self.end.emit()  # emit end signal
                break
            self.timer.emit()


class WriteWorker(QObject):
    def run_task(self):
        print("WriteThread", threading.current_thread())


class Counter(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Counter, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("qthreading test")
        self.resize(300, 120)

        # add a layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lcdNumber = QLCDNumber()
        layout.addWidget(self.lcdNumber)
        # add a pushbutton
        button = QPushButton("start")
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.readThread = ReadThread()  # workthread
        self.writeThread = QThread()  # writeThread
        self.readThread.timer.connect(self.plot)

        self.worker = WriteWorker()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.writeThread)

        self.readThread.timer.connect(self.worker.run_task)

        self.readThread.end.connect(self.end)

        button.clicked.connect(self.work)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def plot(self):
        global sec
        sec += 1
        self.lcdNumber.display(sec)
        print("countTime", threading.current_thread())

    def end(self):
        QMessageBox.information(self, "message", "stop")

    def work(self):
        self.readThread.start()
        self.writeThread.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Counter()
    form.show()
    ret = app.exec_()
    form.writeThread.quit()
    form.writeThread.wait()
    sys.exit(ret)
```

Output:

```
ReadThread1 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 140088050697792)>
ReadThread2 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 140088050697792)>
WriteThread <_DummyThread(Dummy-2, started daemon 140088042305088)>
countTime <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140088409069376)>
ReadThread2 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 140088050697792)>
countTime <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140088409069376)>
WriteThread <_DummyThread(Dummy-2, started daemon 140088042305088)>
ReadThread2 <_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 140088050697792)>
```